# Use new environments for each knitted file in an R Markdown website?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When building an R Markdown website with `rmarkdown::render_site()`, it seems that each of the knitted files all share the same environment and knitr/R Markdown does not create a new empty environment for each individual page. This causes unexpected namespace issues that I can't figure out how to get rid of.

For example, take this minimum working example with the following 5 files:

**testing.Rproj**

```
Version: 1.0

RestoreWorkspace: Default
SaveWorkspace: Default
AlwaysSaveHistory: Default

EnableCodeIndexing: Yes
UseSpacesForTab: Yes
NumSpacesForTab: 2
Encoding: UTF-8

RnwWeave: Sweave
LaTeX: pdfLaTeX

AutoAppendNewline: Yes

BuildType: Website
```

**_site.yml**

```
name: "testing"
navbar:
  title: "Testing"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Step 1"
      href: 01_something.html
    - text: "Step 2"
      href: 02_something-else.html
```

**index.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Testing"
---

Hello, Website!
```

**01_something.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Step 1"
---

Write some data just for fun.

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(here)

write_csv(mtcars, file.path(here(), "cars.csv"))
```
````

**02_something-else.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Step 2"
---

This breaks because `lubridate::here()` and `here::here()` conflict, but *only* when rendering the whole site.

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(here)

# Do something with lubridate
my_date <- ymd("2018-04-19")

# Try to use here() and it breaks when rendering the whole site
# It works just fine when knitting this file on its own, though, since here is loaded after lubridate
cars <- read_csv(file.path(here(), "cars.csv"))
```
````

Both `here` and `lubridate` have a `here()` function, and because I want to use `lubridate`'s throughout the script in `02_something-else.Rmd`, I run `library(here)` after `library(lubridate)`. Running `02_something-else.Rmd` interactively or knitting it by itself works just fine—package loading happens in the right order and everything's great.

However, when building the site with `rmarkdown::render_site()` (from the console, from the "Build" button in RStudio, or from the terminal with `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render_site())"`) there's an error when R gets to `02_something-else.Rmd`:

```
Error: '2018-04-19 14:53:59/cars.csv' does not exist in current working directory
```

Instead of using `here::here()`, R is using `lubridate::here()` and inserting the current date and time, since `library(here)` was originally loaded in `01_something.Rmd` and that environment seems to still be loaded when R gets to `02_something-else.Rmd`.

According to [the documentation for `rmarkdown::render_site()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.9/topics/render_site), you can use the `envir = new.env()` argument to ensure that the site rendering uses a new environment, but that doesn't fix the problem. It seems that guarantees a new environment for the overall site building process, but not for the individual files.

Is there a way to ensure that *each individual file* in an R Markdown website gets its own new environment when knitted?

Comment: I could just use `here::here()` throughout, but that doesn't fix the underlying problem. This can get more complicated with other conflicts too, like `dplyr::filter()` and `MASS::filter()`—if I use MASS in one file in the site, it would mess up code in all the files that come after, but I wouldn't realize it until I build the whole website.

Comment: There is some code here to clear all your loaded packages if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505547/detach-all-packages-while-working-in-r

Comment: Ah cool, that'll work. But it still seems wrong to have to do that at the beginning of each Rmd file, since the theory behind knitting all these files is that they're reproducible on their own.

Comment: Especially since some (like Jenny Bryan) are morally opposed to `rm(list = ls())`: https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

Comment: Update: This is just how R Markdown websites work: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1326#issuecomment-382957907

Comment: A quibble about jargon:  the problem isn't that `here` is loaded, the problem is that it's still "attached", i.e. on the search list.  You can use `detach("package:here")` to remove it.  It's probably worth writing a function to clean up your search list at the start of each new document, given this flaw in `render_site()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a flaw in the design of `rmarkdown::render_site`, but it's easy to work around.  The problem isn't that the `here` package is loaded, the problem is that it's on the search list.  So you should remove it. (Removing things from the search list is easier than unloading them, and is generally pretty safe.)

It seems like a good defensive measure would be to clean up your search list at the start of each document.  This function does that:

```
cleanSearch <- function() {
    defaults <- c(".GlobalEnv", 
                  paste0("package:", getOption("defaultPackages")),
                  "Autoloads",
                  "package:base")
    currentList <- search()  
    deletes <- setdiff(currentList, defaults)
    for (entry in deletes)
      detach(entry, character.only = TRUE)       
}
```

So just call this function before any library calls, and things should be fine.

Edited to add:  oops, I see in the comments you found similar solutions already.   Well, my function looks cleaner than those, and safer....

Comment: Oh cool, this looks safer. I ended up using [this](https://github.com/andrewheiss/rmarkdown-website-envs/blob/master/02_something-else.Rmd), which does a similar thing, but has `unload = TRUE`, which feels more dangerous, so I've removed it from my actual script now.

Comment: Using `sessionInfo()$otherPkgs` bases the test on the package "priority", which is slightly different than basing it on whether they are defaults.  For example, `tools` is typically not a default package, but it won't be detached by your code.