# Sum of column in data table rlang issue

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the following data table :

`structure(list(Date = c("2015-04-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-04-01", 
"2015-04-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-04-01"), Category = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Bakery ", "Branded goods", "Breakfast ", 
"Canned/Packaged ", "Cooking essentials ", "Household ", "NO CATEGORY", 
"Personal care", "Stationary ", "Vehicle accessories"), class = "factor"), 
    Sub_Category = c("carbonated drink ", "carbonated drink ", 
    "carbonated drink ", "Dairy ", "Dairy ", "Stationary "), 
    Product = c("soft drink", "soft drink", "soft drink", "Butter ", 
    "Butter ", "A4 paper"), Brand = c("7 up ", "7 up ", "7 up ", 
    "Amul", "Amul", "NO BRAND"), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), Month = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), MRP = c("55", "25", "70", "37", 
    "37", "0.5"), Quantity = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 20), Sales = c(55, 
    25, 70, 37, 37, 10), Wday = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"), Week = c(13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", "Category", "Sub_Category", 
"Product", "Brand", "Day", "Month", "Year", "MRP", "Quantity", 
"Sales", "Wday", "Week", "X", "X."), sorted = "Date", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001b0788>)`

and I wish to show the sum of(Quantity) or sum(sales) for each type of category for each day spanning the entire date column.

I have tried :

```
data2 <- data %>% group_by(data$Date) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

but i get:

> Error in is_list(x) : object 'rlang_is_list' not found

Also tried :

```
aggregate(cbind(data$Category,data$Sales,data$Quantity)~data$Date,
               data=data,FUN=sum)
```

this produces an entirely different output. ;/

Is there a way to get this done ?

Even after uninstalling rlang,dplyr and ggplot2 package, the error still remains. Is there a way around this ?

Expected output is like so : [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: may not be your problem, but don't use the $ in group_by. Just `group_by(Date)`

Comment: We don't have a reproducble example here, but why use data.table if you are doing everything in dplyr? Or why use dplyr if you have a data.table? Either-way, please provide `dput(head(data))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please check again, as I have updated the question with the dput(head). I had been trying with dplyr, but the "rlang_is" issue keeps hindering it. So i figured i try with data table, using setkey [ ] and then lapply. But it didn't seem to produce any useful output either.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Could you make a reproducible example with package [`reprex`](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex)?

Comment: @9minus4: restart R, then reinstall `rlang` & `dplyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `summarise_at` for `Sales` & `Quantity` only

```r
# calculate total sales
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(Date, Category) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(Sales, Quantity), sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Total = Sales * Quantity)
data2

#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   Date [1]
#>    Date       Category              Sales Quantity Total
#>    <chr>      <fct>                 <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2015-04-01 "Bakery "                 0        0     0
#>  2 2015-04-01 Branded goods             0        0     0
#>  3 2015-04-01 "Breakfast "              0        0     0
#>  4 2015-04-01 "Canned/Packaged "      150        3   450
#>  5 2015-04-01 "Cooking essentials "    74        2   148
#>  6 2015-04-01 "Household "             10       20   200
#>  7 2015-04-01 NO CATEGORY               0        0     0
#>  8 2015-04-01 Personal care             0        0     0
#>  9 2015-04-01 "Stationary "             0        0     0
#> 10 2015-04-01 Vehicle accessories       0        0    NA
```

Then convert from long to wide table using `tidyr::spread`

```r
library(tidyr)
data2_long <- data2 %>% 
  select(-Quantity, -Sales) %>% 
  spread(Category, Total)
data2_long

# A tibble: 1 x 11
# Groups:   Date [1]
  Date       `Bakery ` `Branded goods` `Breakfast ` `Canned/Packaged ` `Cooking essentials ` `Household ` `NO CATEGORY`
  <chr>          <dbl>           <dbl>        <dbl>              <dbl>                 <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 2015-04-01         0               0            0                450                   148          200             0
# ... with 3 more variables: `Personal care` <dbl>, `Stationary ` <dbl>, `Vehicle accessories` <dbl>
```

Data used:

```r
data <- structure(list(Date = c("2015-04-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-04-01", 
    "2015-04-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-04-01"), Category = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Bakery ", "Branded goods", "Breakfast ", 
    "Canned/Packaged ", "Cooking essentials ", "Household ", "NO CATEGORY", 
    "Personal care", "Stationary ", "Vehicle accessories"), class = "factor"), 
    Sub_Category = c("carbonated drink ", "carbonated drink ", 
    "carbonated drink ", "Dairy ", "Dairy ", "Stationary "), 
    Product = c("soft drink", "soft drink", "soft drink", "Butter ", 
    "Butter ", "A4 paper"), Brand = c("7 up ", "7 up ", "7 up ", 
    "Amul", "Amul", "NO BRAND"), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), Month = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), MRP = c("55", "25", "70", "37", 
    "37", "0.5"), Quantity = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 20), Sales = c(55, 
    25, 70, 37, 37, 10), Wday = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"), Week = c(13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X. = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", "Category", "Sub_Category", 
    "Product", "Brand", "Day", "Month", "Year", "MRP", "Quantity", 
    "Sales", "Wday", "Week", "X", "X."), sorted = "Date", 
    class = c("data.frame"), 
    row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

P.S: to solve the `object 'rlang_is_list' not found` problem. Follow the solution in this [answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/difficulty-installing-dev-version-of-ggplot2-due-to-rlang-is-list-not-being-found/8169/8)

> Try launching R from a terminal / console session

```r
R --vanilla
```

> Then, uninstall and reinstall of `rlang` with something like:

```r
remove.packages("rlang")
install.packages("rlang")
```

Comment: hi @Tung Thank you for this. It is indeed helpful. It still throws up the same error : "rlang_list is not found".............. Moreover how can I get this sum for each category for each day. ie 2015-04-01 would have 10 columns beside it for each category and inside is the total of sales made that day for that item category and 2015-04-02 would be for the next .. row wise so as to speak.

Comment: @9minus4: please post your expected output. manually calculate 2 or 3 rows should do it

Comment: Please check now, I have added the expect o/p in the question

Comment: @9minus4: your expected output doesn't match with your data. You need to explain how you come up with that output in the question as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The final solution worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is a much simpler way using `data.table` and `reshape2` on the data you provided

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data2<-dcast(data[,.(Quantity=sum(Quantity),Sales=sum(Sales)),by=.(Category,Date)],Date~Category,value.var = c("Quantity","Sales"),fun.aggregate = sum)
```

You have both the sales and quantity

Comment: You can use the snippet below to remove all packages, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505547/detach-all-packages-while-working-in-r

Comment: This is much simpler indeed! Thank you @SatZ. Very useful