# Clear R environment of all objects & packages

Tags: r

I tried this command

```
remove(list = ls())
```

I expect to clear all R environment (Objects, packages)

Comment: If you also want to clear loaded packages, you can restart R. You can also use `detach`

Comment: @Ronak Shah is there any difference between remove and rm?

Comment: @yarnabrina No, they are not, they are the same function. After defining `rm` the definition is `remove <- rm`. This can be seen in source file `src/library/base/R/rm.R`.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest and, more importantly, *the only reliable* way of doing this is to restart R. That takes care of everything.

Just make sure you’re not accidentally saving the current R image when quitting R.

In RStudio, you need to set the option “Save workspace to .RData file on exit” to “Never”, and disable restoring upon restart — this is *strongly recommended!*

[image: RStudio preferences]

After that, make sure that any previously existing `.RData` files in your project’s folder are deleted (heads up: `.RData` is an *invisible* file so you won’t normally see it in a file browser; you can delete it via the command line).

To restart R from within RStudio, you can use “Session” › “Restart R” or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was already out there :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506112/7902133

According to this answer, the following code should work

```
lapply(paste("package:", names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs), sep=""), 
       detach, 
       character.only = TRUE, 
       unload = TRUE)
```

You may also want to check the first answer for a full description.

Comment: If the question has already an answer elsewhere it should be flagged as duplicate instead of answering it. Please read the FAQ [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/): "It's a duplicate. What do I do?; If you have the privilege to vote to close, click the "close" button under the question, select “duplicate of...”, and paste a link to the duplicate question."; "Should I answer it?; No, not if you think it's a duplicate."

Comment: This will not work reliably if there are dependencies between different loaded packages. Even apart from that it might not reliably reset all session state.

Comment: This "solution" just doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The `freshr` package has consolidated the previous answers into one simple function. Install it via

```
install.packages("freshr")
```

and then run

```r
freshr::freshr()
```

in your console and it will unload all packages and variables for you.

Comment: Frankly, this is a bad approach that attempts to poorly solve a non-exist problem. First off, this package *does not actually work*. It only attempts to unload a *tiny subset* of all loaded packages (`sessionInfo()$otherPkgs` is not complete!), and it may fail if a package cannot be unloaded because another package depends on it. It also completely ignores any non-package code that might require unloading (which is good, because there is no general solution for dealing with such code!). And, as explained in the other answer, this package is completely unnecessary anyway: just restart R.

Comment: … worst of all, by recommending to put `freshr::freshr()` at the top of every script *this package actively promotes poor engineering practices*.