# Problem with installation of devtools package

Tags: r, windows

this is the warning massage I get.
If anyone has an idea If anyone has an idea how to help me, I would greatly appreciate it.

> ```
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not
> currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate
> version of Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
>
>   There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
>          binary source needs_compilation devtools  2.4.4  2.4.5             FALSE
>
> installing the source package ‘devtools’
>
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_2.4.5.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 374718 bytes (365 KB) downloaded 365
> KB
>
> * installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
> ** package 'devtools' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation
> ** R
> ** inst
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :   
> namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.2 is being loaded, but >= 0.5.4 is required
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace ->
> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading
> failed for package 'devtools'
> * removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library/devtools' Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero
> exit status
> ```

I tried to install the package without success. I did not find a guide on the Internet that solved my problem

Comment: You need to install Rtools, have you tried to do so?

Comment: Do heed the all-caps "WARNING" at the beginning of your error message. As for the error message later on, it usually helps to restart R. And make sure that [you are not accidentally saving the current R session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57590056/1968) — doing this creates problems, and is *never* good (but unfortunately easy to do by accident).

Comment: I have the most up to date version of R but when I try to install rtools i get this message:
install.packages("Rtools")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: @tom Again, do actually read the message. Rtools isn’t an *R package*, so you cannot install it via `install.packages`. If you *follow the link* in the message you will find an explanation how to install it.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded it from the website as it said, but have no clue  what to do with it. And still, the warning message didn't change. was I supposed to download it to a specific folder?
thanks,

Comment: you download it and run the .exe to install it.

Comment: of course it was installed on my computer, but the warning massage remain the same:
"WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed."

should I install it on a specific folder on my computer? or change something in the RSTUDIO settings?

Comment: If you installed it to the default location `c:/rtools42` and then restart R/RStudio (completely), then R will find it in the `PATH`. If you installed it in a non-default location, R may still find it, but if not then reading the [docs for Rtools42](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools42/rtools.html) suggests setting the `R_CUSTOM_TOOLS_PATH` envvar to the new path. This needs to be done in windows; if you don't know how, search for "environment var" and set it there, then restart R and RStudio.