# How to empty a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If I restart R my data.table is already filled from previous sessions.
How to make sure to empty a data.table before (re)filling it again?

I searched both google and [data.table/vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) and but could not get any simple answer

[edit] As clarification, I do use vim. I do NOT mind if old data is loaded via .RData I just need to empty one data.table

Comment: sounds like rstudio is loading data from the `.RData` file. Try clicking the broom icon to *clear objects from workspace*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not have RStudio and therefore an easy UI you can remove all objects, including hidden objects, from the global environment with:

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
```

If you want to just clear a specific data table you can simply reassign a blank data table to the object.  For example if dt is your full data table you can do:

```
dt <- data.table()
```

Which will return a blank data table that can then be (re)filled.

Comment: Thank you @dodo1672, that worked! I am using vim as my r IDE. I do have rstudio but I *need* my real vim and not the fake one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely *do not* attempt to empty any data structures manually (otherwise [Jenny Bryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenny_Bryan) will [set your computer on fire](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/)!).

Instead, ensure that R isn’t loading any old data when it gets restarted. Delete any `.RData` file in the current directory (this file is invisible on most systems!), and when quitting R answer “<kbd>n</kbd>o” when asked whether you want to save the workspace.

If you’re using RStudio, [you can configure it to never save/restore data across sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072947/1968).

Comment: Thanks Konrad, The thing is, you do not answer my question. I obviously have my reasons to ask this. So I DO empty only one data.table the rest of the data can stay. So removing .RData or remove the data when closing is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @BastiaanWakkie I urge you to really read the linked blog post. — My advice is precisely because preserving data across sessions *is a bad idea*. If you want to save *specific* data, you’re advised to do so explicitly rather than relying on R’s ill-advised save/restore feature. That is, use the functions [`saveRDS`/`readRDS`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html) to save and restore data explicitly.