# Alternative place to run my R code with more than 1GB RAM over RStudio Cloud

Tags: r, rstudio

For some reason, my RStudio constantly crashes on start up in my windows laptop and I have an important assignment to be written in R soon. Are there any alternatives to RStudio that I can use to do this? My task takes over 1gb RAM which is just over the RStudio cloud limit hence I am unable to use that too.

I've gotten all the codes written down, just need to put them onto the Rstudio. If anyone wouldn't mind downloading the file, put my code down and send me a screenshot of the output, please let me know!

Thank you

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/

Comment: It’s unlikely (though not impossible) that the crash actually has anything to do with RStudio itself. More likely, you’ve got an old `.RData` file lying around which is either corrupt or too large to fit into your memory. Delete that file (and remember that this file might be invisible!), and [don’t save your R workspace in the future when asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072947/1968), it’s never appropriate.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Visual Studio Code

I second the comment that it probably is not Rstudio that causes the problem. But to answer your question:

Visual studio code has an extension for R, that would give you a quite similar experience.

At these links you can read more about [the R extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r) and [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

*Edited to link to the most popular R-package.*

Comment: I'll give this one a go, thank you!

Comment: Got it, I changed the reference to the extensions with fewer requirements.