# can i fix an error in installing binary build in r?

Tags: r, installation, package

whenever a new version update in many (not all packages) comes with a binary build i get this error :

```
* installing *source* package 'raster' ...
** package 'raster' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
* removing 'C:/R/R-4.0.2/library/raster'
* restoring previous 'C:/R/R-4.0.2/library/raster'
Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\R\R-4.0.2\library\00LOCK-raster\raster\libs\x64\raster.dll to C:\R\R-4.0.2\library\raster\libs\x64\raster.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status
```

i need a solution, please

thank you

Comment: That's a Windows specific error, when the package is loaded and you want to install it. Try shutting down R and then running ```install.packages()``` as first command before doing anything else.

Comment: tried it already, does not work , thanks though for the suggestion!

Comment: check if you library contains folders with LOCK in their name and delete them. Sometimes Windows screws up the file lock and then the files can't be changed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There can be more problems in that case. Try one of these:

1. Maybe you need a really fresh session of R, i.e.:

   - click `Session - Restart R` in RStudio, *without restoring the previous session*,
   - or as @RobertHijmans mentions down in the comments, type `unlink(".Rdata")` in your R console and then exit R *without saving your session* and start R again without the nuisance of anything from a previous session getting loaded again.

   Then you can update all packages correctly.
2. Or unload, [`detach()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/detach.html), `raster` package first:

   ```
   detach("package:raster", unload = TRUE)
   install.packages("raster")
   ```

   If that helps and problem occurs in more packages, you can use [Detach all packages while working in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235076/13653858) here on Stack Overflow.
3. Or maybe you need to run R (or RStudio) as Administrator in Windows (right-click the file and choose that option, or find the file in Start menu and choose that option). I don't think it's your case as you have R library outside Program Files, but... things happen.

[image: Run RStudio as admin]

Comment: You can also do `unlink(".Rdata")`  and exit R *without saving your session* and start R again without the nuisance of anything from a previous session getting loaded again.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertHijmans, that's a good point, I have updated the answer with your suggestion!

Comment: does not work and if i uninstall the package completely i get this error when i try to install
`Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'raster'
Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: @IsmailMohsine Then try to manually delete folders `C:\R\R-4.0.2\library\00LOCK-raster` (if exists) and `C:\R\R-4.0.2\library\raster`, run RGui rather than RStudio and run `install.packages("raster")`. There are so many possible causes of this error that's hard to find the correct solution, but hope we'll find that!

Comment: there is no 00LOCK-raster folder , and when i removed the library completely then tried to reinstall it in Rgui i get the same message as i mentioned in my last comment